# How to Show Activity at the time of orientation change in Android?

Tags: android

When I turn the device from  portrait to landscape at that time my activity is restarted. For that Activity I need to use both portrait and landscape mode.

How to Show my `Activity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line in manifest file  `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`   here

```
<activity android:name=".imgview"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"   
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and where u can override for restart . in my functions it's update listitems and some other function  : example

```
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.e("ScreenMode",""+screenMode); 
        if(screenMode==1)
        {Log.e("ScreenMode",""+screenMode);
            buildUrl(result,startPage);
            showImageList();
        }

        if(screenMode==2)
        {
            showOneImage(forFunc);
        }
        if(screenMode==0)
        {
            startOMG();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting restarted use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your `AndroidManifest` for your `Activity`.